Unity switch from the menu to the game with a click on button
Hi I'm creating a game with unity it is my first time working with Unity and I struggle to switch from the menu to the actual game.
I started developping my game so when I click the play button the grid of the game automatically shows up.
But I want to have a menu before going into the game so I added a canvas with a button so that when I click the button the change happens.
However I am kinda lost because when I press play both elements show up, the grid and the button whcih is normal because I haven't configured the logic but I'm not sure how to do it. I created a GameManager object as it was recommended by most guides and a script.
Here is the script of my gamemanager:
public class GameManager : MonoBehaviour

{
    public static GameManager Instance;
    public GameObject menuCanvas;
    public GridManager gridManager;

    public GameState State;

    private void Awake()
    {
        Instance = this;
    }

    private void Start()
    {
        ChangeState(GameState.Menu);
    }

    public void ChangeState(GameState newState)
    {
        State = newState;

        switch (State)
        {
            case GameState.Menu:
                break;
            case GameState.GameSearch:
                break;
            case GameState.Victory:
                break;
            case GameState.Lose:
                break;
            default:
                throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException (nameof(State), newState, null);
        }


    }

    public void OnPlayNowClicked()
    {
        menuCanvas.SetActive(false); // this method is just for testing
    }
}

public enum GameState
{
    Menu = 0,
    GameSearch = 1,
    Victory = 2,
    Lose = 3
}

I have enum at the end for all the different state my game offers, on the Start method I set the state to Menu first.
If I understand correctly I must link my button OnClick event to my ChangeState() method right? For some reason I'm not sure I can't select this method in the unity button pannel. Secondly, how do I pass a different GameState parameter to it?

tbh this code has mostly nothing to do with any of it, all the state stuff isnt used.. so the only could you might be using is the OnPlayNowClicked, and thats it..  so from this we cant tell whats going on either.

To call ChangeState when clicking a button, you have to first reference the button in the code
//at the very beggining
using UnityEngine.UI;

public class GameManager : MonoBehaviour

{
    //...
    //in your variable declarations
    public Button playButton;

Then reference the button in the Inspector in the Unity editor
At the start method, subscribe to the Button's onclick event
private void Start()
{
    ChangeState(GameState.Menu);
    playButton.onClick.AddListener(()=>{ChangeState(GameState.GameSearch);})
}

This will call ChangeState(GameState.GameSearch) when clicking the button
Hope this helps

Thanks it works, I also found another way of doing this as well.
